# How do I evaluate the limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate limit$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2}}{x}$$ For my answer I got $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. My professor answer sheet says $\frac{\sqrt2}{4}$. I am not sure why that is. My work and problem is attached below. Thank you.

[image: Work]

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Note $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2(\sqrt{2})^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answers are equivalent, as noted in the comments.

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt 2} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2}}_{=1} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt 2} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2 \cdot 2} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Please remember to check your work thoroughly before submitting it, anywhere for that matter!!

Comment: Yes thank you for the reminder and solution. My algebra is rusty haha.